# Connecting Arduino and Android Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino, android-bluetooth, arduino-uno

I tried to connect arduino and Android via bluetooth and it's working pretty good. But while initialising the connection I wrote a setup in my arduino I don't know how to call it.

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Genotronex.begin(9600);
  Genotronex.println("Bluetooth On please press 1 or 0 blink LED ..");
  pinMode(ledpin,OUTPUT);
}
```

Here is my code in android

```
void beginListenForData()
            {
                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                final byte delimiter = 10; //This is the ASCII code for a newline character

                stopWorker = false;
                readBufferPosition = 0;
                readBuffer = new byte[1024];
                workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
                {
                    public void run()
                    {
                        while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopWorker)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                int bytesAvailable = mmInputStream.available();
                                if(bytesAvailable > 0)
                                {
                                    byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                                    mmInputStream.read(packetBytes);
                                    for(int i=0;i<bytesAvailable;i++)
                                    {
                                        byte b = packetBytes[i];
                                        if(b == delimiter)
                                        {
                                            byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
                                            System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0, encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.length);
                                            final String data = new String(encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");
                                            readBufferPosition = 0;

                                            handler.post(new Runnable()
                                            {
                                                public void run()
                                                {
                                                    myLabel.setText(data);
                                                }
                                            });
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            readBuffer[readBufferPosition++] = b;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                            }
                            catch (IOException ex)
                            {
                                stopWorker = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

                workerThread.start();
            }
```

Help me Out here. What I exactly is want is when I open the connection from android it should show `Bluetooth On please press 1 or 0 blink LED`.. Also How to do the listener in my android if I have the timer set up.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure u have trouble in setup function check the structure Genotronex that whether it is errorfree. Also check using the device with varying baud rates like 57600,115200.